# Zookeeper issue in setting kafka

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

To install kafka , I downloaded the kafka tar folder. To start the server I tried this command :

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

The following error occured on entering the above command:

```
INFO Reading configuration from: config/zookeeper.properties (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2014-08-21 11:53:55,748] FATAL Invalid config, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)
org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig$ConfigException: Error processing config/zookeeper.properties
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:110)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:76)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: config/zookeeper.properties file is missing
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:94)
    ... 2 more
Invalid config, exiting abnormally
```

Is it that I need to setup zookeeper separately? How could I resolve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is basically because of this 
 
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: config/zookeeper.properties file is missing`

it would be really useful if you could share what exactly have you done so far. Also check if the same file exists at the said location and you are running the command from the correct location .. it is supposed to be run from your `$KAFKA_HOME` folder (where you've extracted the tar file)

Comment: So far I have only downloaded kafka tar folder and ran the above command. It has zookeeper.properties file inside config folder. Zookeeper file has the following in it:                            """# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# disable the per-ip limit on the number of connections since this is a non-production config
maxClientCnxns=0  """                                                     Inside /temp I created zookeeper folder. What has to be created inside the folder?

Comment: from where did you run this? you are supposed to run this from inside your kafka home folder (where you've extracted the tar)

Comment: Thank you.. I was running it inside bin folder of kafka.. That was the mistake.

Answer (score 21):

For Windows:

1. Go to `kafka_2.11-2.0.0\bin\windows` folder
2. Then run `zookeeper-server-start.bat ../../config/zookeeper.properties`

Comment: Notice that for windows there is a special folder so you need to go up two times `../../`
The same for `kafka-server-start.sh ../../config/server.properties`

Answer (score 4):

I too faced the same issue when I installed kafka from Brew on Macbook

This is happening because the zookeeper.properties file is not in config of bin.

Follow these step.

1. Enter the command---> cd /usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.3.0
2. Enter the command ---->cd libex
3. Now enter the command--->zookeeper-server-start config/zookeeper.properties

You will get the INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory) Message.

**Earlier I was getting this error:**

$ zookeeper-server-start config/zookeeper.properties
[2019-10-02 14:35:20,159] INFO Reading configuration from: config/zookeeper.properties (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2019-10-02 14:35:20,160] ERROR Invalid config, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)
org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig$ConfigException: Error processing config/zookeeper.properties
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:156)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:104)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:81)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: config/zookeeper.properties file is missing
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:140)
    ... 2 more
Invalid config, exiting abnormally

Answer (score 2):

I saw when you run the above command it doesn't take config file. So if you Put complete path like `c:\Kafka\config\zookeeper.properties`... this works.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact same error, and after a while I realized that the reason for the error was, I wasn't able to find the `zookeeper.properties` file, and that was because the path wasn't correct, I installed kafka through brew so the config folder was created inside libexec, so find where the config directory is and check for `zookeeper.properties` inside it and give that path.

Comment: This fixed me up! Thanks!
I didn't know the config file was inside libexec (also installed form homebrew)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.

I was following [this](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart) guide and step 2 mentions to run this command:
    bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
I had 2 problems, that first was that I wasn't inside the root directory of the file you untar and the second was that I didn't copy the complete command. Make sure both of them are correct and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that whether **/config** folder exist or not.

Try to type properties directly. e.g. **zookeeper-server-start zookeeper.properties**

I installed it with homebrew, it works.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `bin/windows` is added to the path but `kafka/config` is not.
Just navigate to your kafka folder and then try to run.
I am adding screenshot if it can help.

Before
[image]

After
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powershell as an alternative to CMD.

Consider `myKafka` is your kafka home directory, Extract your kafka tar file here.
Extracted folder(KafkaDir) will be having `./bin,/config`, etc. internal folders.

1. Now, open Powershell prompt, go to myKafka folder.
2. Run below command:

```
.\kafkaDir\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat
.\kafkaDir\config\zookeeper.properties
```

Zookeeper will get start.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the absolute path to:

```
$KAFKA_HOME/config/zookeeper.properties
```

For me I used:

```
$KAFKA_HOME = /usr/local/kafka
```

Answer (score 0):

In \bin\windows\kafka-run-class.bat add the file content

```
rem Classpath addition for release
for %%i in ("%BASE_DIR%\libs\*") do (
    call :concat "%%i"
)
```

### // Section to Add

---

```
rem Classpath addition for LSB style path
if exist %BASE_DIR%\share\java\kafka\* (
    call :concat %BASE_DIR%\share\java\kafka\*
)
**
```

### // Above Section to Add

```
rem Classpath addition for core
for %%i in ("%BASE_DIR%\core\build\libs\kafka_%SCALA_BINARY_VERSION%*.jar") do (
    call :concat "%%i"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error fix with this,
to read your config file use ....\config\zookeeper.properties(dot dot \dot dot\config\zookeeper.properties)

> kafka\bin\windows>zookeeper-server-start.bat ....\config\zookeeper.properties

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

Have to run in from Kafka home directory, but you are running from the bin.

Comment: Always add answer which could help somebody, and answer in the context, by reading such meaningless answer you tend to waste others time.The best way to include scripts which you used to run so that others might get evidence what you wrote is meaningful.