# Zookeeper error: dataDir is not set

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am using the kafka quickstart tutorial to set a producer-consumer connection.
https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

I have been using this tutorial for a while and it worked perfectly until now.
When I run zookeeper:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

I get the following error:

```
[2017-01-14 18:57:18,148] INFO Reading configuration from: config/server.properties (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2017-01-14 18:57:18,159] ERROR Invalid config, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)
org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig$ConfigException: Error processing config/server.properties
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:123)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:101)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataDir is not set
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parseProperties(QuorumPeerConfig.java:243)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:119)
... 2 more
Invalid config, exiting abnormally
```

This happened after killing manually some tail processes. How can I overcome this error? I already downloaded a new kafka quickstart folder but the error continues. My zookeeper.config file:

```
...
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# disable the per-ip limit on the number of connections since this is a non-production config
maxClientCnxns=0
```

Thank you!

Comment: You did not set 'dataDir' in config/zookeeper.properties. Check the file to ensure it's configured as expected.

Comment: Hi! My zookeeper.properties file has dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper/ also clientPort=2181 and maxClientCnxns=0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zookeeper issue in setting kafka](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25421758/zookeeper-issue-in-setting-kafka)

Comment: I have seen that post, but it's not the same error

Comment: The zookeeper properties file you mean is config/zookeeper.properties, right?

Comment: Yes, if you download the kafka package it is in the config folder

Comment: This happened to me right after I killed some tail processes

Comment: Can anyone help here?

Comment: If you already have it, delete /tmp/zookeeper dir and try again.

Comment: Hi! I do not have that directory..

Answer (score 7):

The guide is actually mistaken ... in order to start Zookeeper you should point to the config/zookeeper.properties file instead.

Comment: this worked for me, Quickstart from Kafka page is wrong, as stated here just do:

bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
instead of
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/server.properties

Answer (score 4):

Your start command says `config/zookeeper.properties` but your error message references `config/server.properties`.

Zookeeper should be started with `zookeeper.properties` and Kafka should be started with `server.properties`.

Don't get these mixed up or neither will start

Answer (score 3):

Try this for windows:

For zookeeper:

```
.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties
```

For Kafka Server:

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
```